# Подбор цвета с оттенком

Tags: javascript

Необходимо динамически создавать линейный градиент, на основе **одного** выбранного (из колорпикера) цвета. Проблема в том, как подобрать второй цвет, если пользователь выбрал один?

Как подобрать цвет темнее/светлее от выбранного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам скорее всего надо делать преобразование в другую систему цвета, например в систему [HSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL)

> цветовая модель, в которой цветовыми координатами являются тон, насыщенность и светлота

### RGB to HSL

```
/**
* Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
* adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
* Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
* returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
*
* @param   Number  r       The red color value
* @param   Number  g       The green color value
* @param   Number  b       The blue color value
* @return  Array           The HSL representation
*/
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}
```

### HSL to RGB

```
/**
* Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
* adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
* Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
* returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
*
* @param   Number  h       The hue
* @param   Number  s       The saturation
* @param   Number  l       The lightness
* @return  Array           The RGB representation
*/
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
var r, g, b;

if(s == 0){
    r = g = b = l; // achromatic
}else{
    var hue2rgb = function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
        if(t < 0) t += 1;
        if(t > 1) t -= 1;
        if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
        if(t < 1/2) return q;
        if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
        return p;
    }

    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
    var p = 2 * l - q;
    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
}

return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
}
```

Т.е. получая 1 цвет от пользователя переведя его в систему цвета HSL и уменьшив/увеличив светлоту, вы переводите обратно в RGB и получаете второй цвет для градиента, который будет темнее/светлее выбранного пользователем.
Так же многие браузеры поддерживают цвета HSL непосредственно: [Поддержка HSL браузерами](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/color)
Не забудьте проверять пределы изменения светлоты (она меняется в диапазоне от 0 до 1)

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Буду разбираться.

Comment: ДА! Получилось!!! Отлично!!! Работает!!!))))

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-element-background-color").change(function($this) {
    var c = $(this).val();

    //HEX to RGB
    var r = parseInt(c.substring(1, 3), 16);
    var g = parseInt(c.substring(3, 5), 16);
    var b = parseInt(c.substring(5, 7), 16);

    $("#rgb").css({
      "background": c
    });

    //RGB to HSL
    var hsl = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);


    var h = parseFloat(hsl[0]);
    var s = parseFloat(hsl[1]);
    var l = parseFloat(hsl[2]);

    //set second color
    l = l - 0.11;
    s = s - 0.09;
    h = h + 0.01;

    //HSL to RGB
    var rgb = hslToRgb(h, s, l);

    //RGB to HEX
    var rgb = toHEX(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

    $("#hsl").css({
      "background": rgb
    });

    $("#gr").css({
      "background": "linear-gradient(to top, " + rgb + " , " + c + ")"
    });

    $("#d3").css({
      "background": c,
      "box-shadow": "0 8px 0 0 " + rgb
    });
  });
});


function toHEX(r, g, b) {
  return '#' + ((b | g << 8 | r << 16) | 1 << 24).toString(16).slice(1);
}

/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
  } else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
      case r:
        h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
        break;
      case g:
        h = (b - r) / d + 2;
        break;
      case b:
        h = (r - g) / d + 4;
        break;
    }
    h /= 6;
  }

  return [h, s, l];
}


function hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
  var r, g, b;

  if (s == 0) {
    r = g = b = l; // achromatic
  } else {
    var hue2rgb = function hue2rgb(p, q, t) {
      if (t < 0) t += 1;
      if (t > 1) t -= 1;
      if (t < 1 / 6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
      if (t < 1 / 2) return q;
      if (t < 2 / 3) return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6;
      return p;
    }

    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
    var p = 2 * l - q;
    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
  }

  return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
}
```

```css
#rgb,
#hsl,
#gr,
#d3 {
  display: block;
  padding: 22px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='input-element-background-color'>Выберите цвет</label>
<input type='color' id='input-element-background-color'>
<div id='rgb'>Выбранный цвет</div>
<div id='hsl'>Новый цвет</div>
<div id='gr'>gradient</div>
<div id='d3'>3d</div>
```